# powershell expand archive split string name

Tags: powershell, split

I want to unzip a file and split the extension of filename.
However with expand archive its not working.

I get the error: Parameter "." is not allowed

```
$path = "C:\AD\"
$filename "Test.zip"

Expand-Archive -Path $path\$filename -DestinationPath $path\$filename.split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Expand-Archive -Path "$path$filename" -DestinationPath "$path$filename".split('.')[0]
```